# PHP Redis Lua s script issue

Tags: redis, lua, phpredis

I want to use lua script to make atomic Redis operation using php/reids extension, so my code is:

```
    $command = "
        local hashes = redis.call('smembers', ARGV[1])
        for  hash in pairs(hashes) do
            local keys = redis.call('hkeys', hash)
            for key in pairs(keys) do
                redis.call('hset', key, 0)
            end
        end

        return 1
    ";
    $result = $this->redisClient->evaluate($command, [self::ALL_HASHES]);
```

this script should take all availavle hashes from `self::ALL_HASHES` set, loop through each hash, and set value for each hash key to 0. Script is passing, and `$error = $this->redisClient->getLastError();` is `null`, but values are not 0. What I'm doing wrong? I'm new to Lua, it's my first script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You script has 2 problems. First of all, you should use `ipairs` to iterate the array, instead of `pairs`. `pairs` only iterates the key part of the table, and in this case, it iterates the array index. Second, your `HSET` command misses the key part. Try the following code:

```
local hashes = redis.call('smembers', ARGV[1])
for i, hash in ipairs(hashes) do
    local keys = redis.call('hkeys', hash)
    for j, key in ipairs(keys) do
        redis.call('hset', hash, key, 0)
    end
end

return 1
```

Comment: hmmm, let me try, btw I tried `ipairs` and also has some issue, maybe it's b-z I miss the key part

Comment: @ItamarHaber That's my pleasure :)